# What are the best $3$ pocket cards in Omaha poker?

Tags: probability, card-games, poker

In *Texas Hold'em poker*, the best $3$ pocket cards are AA, KK and QQ respectively.

I've been trying to find the best $3$ pocket cards in *Omaha poker*, where you have to use exactly $2$ pocket cards out of $4$ given to you, and exactly $3$ community cards out of $5$ opened on table.

Therefore, $4$ aces, for example, are not so good because you can only use $2$ aces.

The other $2$ aces are a waste, and thus they also won't open in community cards.

So what are the best $3$ pocket cards in *Omaha poker*, and with how much % of win?

Comment: AAKK with two suits probably.

Comment: Your question was very poorly phrased (IMHO). I've edited it; make sure it is accurately phrased.

Comment: There are a few sites for experimentation that are nice. Here is one: http://www.propokertools.com/simulations After selecting Omaha Hi, you can look at how a hand compares to another hand or how it plays against a random hand or even a range of hands. "*" represents a random hand, while something like "As Ac Ks Kc" represents "Ace and King of spades with Ace and King of clubs". (The button for syntax help explains how to enter hands into the calculuator.)